# Аннотации в java, тип Date в поле

Tags: java, аннотации

Создаю аннотацию в java, и компилятор не позволяет указать полю аннотации тип Date, кто знает почему?

```
import java.util.Date;

public @interface MyMethodInfo {

     Date value();

}
```

Comment: в значениях аннотации может быть только константа или стринг. Нельзя там быть объекту из кучи. Разве сообщение об ошибке это не говорит?

Comment: invalid type for element {0} of annotation type, а почему не говорит

Comment: Спасибо за ответ